# What is the smallest integer $n$>1 such that $n^{5000}+n^{2013}+1$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Which is the smallest integer $n>1$, such that $$n^{5000}+n^{2013}+1$$ is prime ?
 Since $x^{5000}+x^{2013}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ and has value $1$ for $x=0$,
 there should be infinitely many such $n$, if Bunyakovsky's conjecture is
 true.

Comment: Peter, assuming you were the user who suggested the edit, [see this page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) for help getting access to your account again.

Comment: Mathematica says $n^{5000}+n^{2013}+1$ is not prime for $1<n<3000$.

Comment: According to Maple is not prime for $1<n<5000$.

Answer (score 13):

$n=23205$ produces the smallest prime value of the polynomial (aside from the trivial $n=1$). Interestingly, $23205=3\times 5\times 7\times 13\times 17$.

$n\in\{44579, 55754, 78120, 78515, 94154, 99045\}$ produce all the remaining primes with $n<10^5$. In all cases, [OpenPFGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/) has been used to find the primes and prove primality using Brillhart-Lehmer-Selfridge method.

Comment: I can't imagine the number of digits the number has. And I can't even be sure that it is a prime.

Comment: I'd be happy to see someone confirm my findings using an independent tool for checking primality of large numbers (there are quite a few of them). As for the number of digits, the prime corresponding to $n=23205$ has 21828 digits and the one for $n=55754$ has 23732 of them.

Comment: Well, I assume an elementary approach to the problem is still open.

Comment: Certainly so; at the moment we don't even know if the search would finish at all.

Comment: All $3$ values check out using Mathematica's PrimeQ function.  I'm not sure what method it uses to test for primality.